# Application.DisplayAlerts = False in Excel object created in Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

This is a macro to update a report. This file would need to overwrite the existing file.

With `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` I still get the pop up saying this file exists and if I want to replace.

Is there something wrong with my code or is there a method to automatically click yes?

```
Sub DailyRefresh ()
    'Open and refresh Access
    Dim appAccess As Object
    Set appAccess = GetObject("S:\Shared\DailyRefresh.accdb")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    appAccess.Visible = True
    appAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro "Run_All_Queries"
    appAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase

   'Open Excel

    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open ("s:\Shared\Template.xlsx")
    xl.Visible = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
'Set date to the 1st of the Month on Summary tab
    xl.Sheets("Summary").Visible = True
    xl.Sheets("Summary").Select
    xl.Range("C10").Value = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), 1)
    xl.Range("C10").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"

' REFRESH Table
    xl.Sheets("Data").Visible = True
    xl.Sheets("Data").Select
    xl.Range("A1").Select
    xl.Range("DailyRefresh.accdb[[#Headers],[ACTIVITY_DT]]").Select
    xl.Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    xl.Worksheets("Fname").Visible = True
    xl.Sheets("Fname").Select
    
     
'Copy and Save AS
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Path = "S:\Shared\NewTemplate"
    Filename = xl.Sheets("Fname").Range("A7").Value
    xl.SaveAs Path & Filename & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False
    xl.Worksheets("Fname").Visible = False
    xl.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: If you know where the file is you could do a `Kill FilePath`  and delete it ahead of time to dodge the overwrite prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

refers to the application where your code is running, not the Excel instance you created.

```
xl.DisplayAlerts = False
```

would be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to use Application.DisplayAlerts = False exactly before the line(**s**) that are taking time (**no other lines between them**). I had the same problem, because I was using it just once, but after each line that calls an external app, when it is back to VBA, it goes back to true.